# Is there any better way to classify narration based on keywords in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, text-classification, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to classify narrations based on certain keyword dictionary. My approach is to identify the keyword with the least string distance with the narration. This works fairly well, but I encountered one example where this approach didn't seem appropriate. Following is a snippet of the code

```
#a is the narration and b(s) are some keywords
a = "PRAJA GHUPTA UTAMA Trf Inw RTGS PT BANK NEGARA INDONESIA (PERSERO) TBKPRAJA GHUPTA UTAMA"
b1 = "tarik"
b2 = "pajak"
b3 = "trf inw rtgs"

#After loading stringdist library
dis1 = stringdist(tolower(a),b1,method = "jw") 
dis2 = stringdist(tolower(a),b2,method = "jw")
dis3 = stringdist(tolower(a),b3,method = "jw")

#Output 
> dis1
[1] 0.3810606

> dis2
[1] 0.3143939

> dis3
[1] 0.4406566
```

From what I understand, stringdist function first recycles the shorter length string to match the longer length and then calculates the disctance based on the number of iterations needed to match both the strings.

What I don't understand is, `b3` being a sub string of the narration `a`, yet does not have the closet distance compared to other key words.

Wanted to know if there's any reason behind it and what other alternative approach I can try for better matching?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to note that `stringdist()` applies to characters, while the question appears to want to find word similarity 
Hence consider the following:

```
# Note this does not attempt to explain all nuances, but only the word versus character aspect:
a = "PRAJA GHUPTA UTAMA Trf Inw RTGS PT BANK NEGARA INDONESIA (PERSERO) TBKPRAJA GHUPTA UTAMA"
b1 = "tarik"      
b2 = "pajak"
b3 = "trf inw rtgs"
b4 = "PRAJA GHUPTA"   # exactly same char. seq. but nchar = 11 - higher score     
b5 = "PRAJA G"        # exactly same char. seq. but nchar = 6  - lower score
b6 = "PRAJA G"        # same, stringdist(b5,b6,method = "jw") = 0 as expected
b7 = "paa gua uaa"    # dis7 = stringdist(tolower(a),b7,method = "jw")
library(stringdist)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
#After loading stringdist library
dis1 = stringdist(tolower(a),b1,method = "jw") 
dis2 = stringdist(tolower(a),b2,method = "jw")
dis3 = stringdist(tolower(a),b3,method = "jw")
dis4 = stringdist(tolower(a),b4,method = "jw")
dis5 = stringdist(tolower(a),b5,method = "jw")
dis6 = stringdist(b5,b6,method = "jw")

# This uses b7, where b7 nchar=9, but only 4 unique chars p,a,g & u - all available early
dis7 = stringdist(tolower(a),b7,method = "jw")   # relatively 2nd lowest score : 0.2916667


dis1;dis2;dis3;dis4;dis5; dis6; dis7

> dis1;dis2;dis3;dis4;dis5; dis6; dis7
[1] 0.3810606
[1] 0.3143939
[1] 0.4406566
[1] 0.635101
[1] 0.6152597
[1] 0
[1] 0.2916667

# other aspects are explained in the vignette /help pages
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense now. Do let me know if you know of any good method or references to classify words (instead of characters). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Great ... This is a very active domain currently - check some of these basic links for ideas to pursue: https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes;   
https://rpubs.com/lmullen/nlp-chapter;   
https://sweetcode.io/how-to-text-mine-in-r-using-nlp-techniques/;    
https://hub.packtpub.com/9-useful-r-packages-for-nlp-text-mining/ ;  ...................................................................                                                                                                            If this (/any other answers/posts) is useful to you please accept the answer /vote+, thanks.